# Windows Integrated Authentication with IIS Farm and subapplications

Tags: iis, authentication, kerberos

Assume the following site layout

1. www.contoso.com - runs as CONTOSO\sitePool
2. www.contoso.com/subSite1 - runs as CONTOSO\subPool1
3. www.contoso.com/subSite2 - runs as CONTOSO\subPool2

The pages should use Kerberos for authentication - so I assigned the SPN *HTTP/www.contoso.com* to *CONTOSO\sitePool*, which works nice for the www.contoso.com site.

Now I want to use Kerberos for subsite1 and subsite2, too.
I cannot assign the SPN to the pools, since it is already assigned.
I also can't assign an SPN in the form of *HTTP/www.contoso.com/subSiteX*, since browser are not aware of this (they calculate the needed SPN with the domain name only).

So how can I use Kerberos Authentication in the sub-sites?

Comment: First off, what version of IIS are we talking about here?

Comment: It's about IIS 8.5, but an answer would probaly apply to 7 also.

Answer (score 1):

To put it short, you can't use Kerberos for subsites with different delegated pricipals.

Kerberos SPN has no provisions beyond [service]/[name]:[port/service] .

Your options are:

- Run subsites at different ports and create SPN with Delegation for each service user with different ports.
- Use NTLM
- Use same Application Pool account for all subsites

Comment: That's a pity...   
Exchange does it with an "Alternate Service Account" (or similar).

Comment: ASA still will not allow duplicate SPN's. It's basically sharing a service user account across servers. As Exchange runs in machine context (not using AD service accounts), it uses ASA "machine account" to handle Kerberos and SPNs.

Comment: I know, but one could use this in IIS to allow Kerberos in subapplications easily - specify an spn holding account per web application - independent from the app pool account.

Comment: You could use different URLs for subsites with different SPNs. Eg server site.com/subsite from subsite.com/subsite1 etc.That's what ASA is essentially for - loadbalancer has different URL/SPN than your main application at root URL/SPN. This is not a solution for what you're asking though.

Answer (score 0):

This article/blog post might apply.

It indicates that using negotiate will automatically use kerberos.

Here is a cmd to disable NTLM
appcmd.exe set config "mysite" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /-"providers.[value='NTLM']" /commit:apphost

the /-"providers.[value='NTLM']" is to remove.  If you wanted to add an auth provider you would do this.

appcmd.exe set config "mysite" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /+"providers.[value='NTLM']" /commit:apphost

Your just changing the - to + in front of the provider.

Here is just a good article from IIS.com regarding windows auth providers.
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/providers

Best of luck, hopefully this is helpful

Comment: My question was not about how to use Kerberos or how to force Kerberos, but how to use Kerberos with subsitees. Thanks for hints anyway.